# Get Item from document library using server relative url

Tags: jsom, library, file, item

Value does not fall within the expected range.

```
  function getFileProperties(url,success,error) {
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
   var relUrl = url.replace(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl,'');  //convert to relative url
   var file = ctx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(relUrl);   //get file
   ctx.load(file,"'ListItemAllFields'"); 

   ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      function () {
         success(file);
      }, 
      error
   );
}

getFileProperties('https://unileverdev.sharepoint.com/sites/Test%20Documents/GLOBAL pnp 2017-02-27.css',
  function(file){
     var listItem = file.get_listItemAllFields();
     console.log(listItem);
  },
  function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());
  });
```

Comment: I am getting error Value does not fall within the expected range

Answer (score 1):

```
function getFileProperties(url,success,error) {

   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
   //var relUrl = url.replace(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl,'');  //convert to relative url
   var file = ctx.get_web().getFileByUrl(url);   //get file
   ctx.load(file); 

   ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      function () {
         success(file);
      }, 
      error
   );
}
getFileProperties('https://unileverdev.sharepoint.com/sites/Test_Vishwa/Test%20Documents/GLOBAL pnp 2017-02-27.css',
  function(file){
     var listItem = file.get_listItemAllFields();
     var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
     ctx.load(listItem);
     ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      function () {
         listItem.get_item('Title')
         console.log(listItem)
      }, 
      function(){
        console.log(args.get_message());
      }
   );
     console.log(listItem);
  },
  function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());
  });
```

Comment: Update code It works for me

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.

```
 function getFileProperties(url,success,error) {
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
   var relUrl = url.replace(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl,'');  //convert to relative url
   var file = ctx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(relUrl);   //get file
   ctx.load(file,"'ListItemAllFields'"); 

   ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      function () {
         success(file);
      }, 
      error
   );
}

getFileProperties('/sites/Test%20Documents/GLOBAL pnp 2017-02-27.css',
  function(file){
     var listItem = file.get_listItemAllFields();
     console.log(listItem);
  },
  function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());
  });
```

Hope it will works for you.

Comment: It is giving error ListItemAllFields not defined